# NoMethodError Rails 4 App -> Nested attribute issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am working on a Rails 4 App, one of my modules is a general patrol report in which a user creates a report based on his / her shift shift start / stop. after the report is created they have the option to go back into the report view and add a patrol report.

Every thing is working up to the gen_rep_ent form submission.

**The specific error I get is:**

```
 undefined method `general_report=' for #<GenRepEnt:0x007f871d9ea150>
```

followed by:

```
  def create              
    @general_report = GeneralReport.find(params[:general_report_id])
    @gen_rep_ent = GenRepEnt.new(gen_rep_ent_params)
    @gen_rep_ent.general_report = @gen_rep_ent <-- Problem Line

    respond_to do |format|
      if @gen_rep_ent.save
        format.html { redirect_to @general_report, notice: 'General Report Entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @general_report}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @general_report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

It is the 3rd line that is causing the issue here.

My general_report model has the following relationship:

```
has_many :gen_rep_ents, dependent: :destroy
```

My Routes File looks Like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :mobile_alarm_reports

  resources :mobile_incident_reports

  resources :static_incident_reports

  resources :general_reports do 
    resources :gen_rep_ents, except: [:index], controller: 'general_reports/gen_rep_ents'
  end

  resources :visitor_parkings

  resources :residents

  resources :sites

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

  # Adds Static Pages 
  root 'home#index'

  get 'home/about'

  get 'home/contact'

  get 'home/pricing'
```

My show file looks like:

```
<% @gen_rep_ents.each do |gen_rep_ent| %>
  <table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Report</th>
      </tr>     
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= gen_rep_ent.time %></td>
        <td><%= gen_rep_ent.report %></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

gen_rep_ents_controller.rb: <-- The nested Item

```
class GeneralReports::GenRepEntsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gen_rep_ent, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /gen_rep_ents
  # GET /gen_rep_ents.json
  def index
    @gen_rep_ents = GenRepEnt.all
  end

  # GET /gen_rep_ents/1
  # GET /gen_rep_ents/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /gen_rep_ents/new
  def new
    @general_report = GeneralReport.find(params[:general_report_id])
    @gen_rep_ent = GenRepEnt.new
  end

  # GET /gen_rep_ents/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /gen_rep_ents
  # POST /gen_rep_ents.json
  def create
    @general_report = GeneralReport.find(params[:general_report_id])
    @gen_rep_ent = GenRepEnt.new(gen_rep_ent_params)
    @gen_rep_ent.general_report = @gen_rep_ent

    respond_to do |format|
      if @gen_rep_ent.save
        format.html { redirect_to @general_report, notice: 'General Report Entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @general_report}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @general_report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /gen_rep_ents/1
  # PATCH/PUT /gen_rep_ents/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gen_rep_ent.update(gen_rep_ent_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gen_rep_ent, notice: 'General Report Entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gen_rep_ent }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gen_rep_ent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /gen_rep_ents/1
  # DELETE /gen_rep_ents/1.json
  def destroy
    @gen_rep_ent.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to gen_rep_ents_url, notice: 'General Report Entry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_gen_rep_ent
      @gen_rep_ent = GenRepEnt.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def gen_rep_ent_params
      params.require(:gen_rep_ent).permit(:time, :report, :general_report)
    end
end
```

The general_reports_controller: <-- Parent Item

```
class GeneralReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_general_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /general_reports
  # GET /general_reports.json
  def index
    @general_reports = GeneralReport.all
  end

  # GET /general_reports/1
  # GET /general_reports/1.json
  def show
    @general_report = GeneralReport.find(params[:id])
    @gen_rep_ents = @general_report.gen_rep_ents
  end

  # GET /general_reports/new
  def new
    @general_report = GeneralReport.new
  end

  # GET /general_reports/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /general_reports
  # POST /general_reports.json
  def create
    @general_report = GeneralReport.new(general_report_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @general_report.save
        format.html { redirect_to @general_report, notice: 'General report was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @general_report }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @general_report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /general_reports/1
  # PATCH/PUT /general_reports/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @general_report.update(general_report_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @general_report, notice: 'General report was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @general_report }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @general_report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /general_reports/1
  # DELETE /general_reports/1.json
  def destroy
    @general_report.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to general_reports_url, notice: 'General report was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_general_report
      @general_report = GeneralReport.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def general_report_params
      params.require(:general_report).permit(:user_id, :site_id, :date, :shift_start, :shift_end, :gp_number)
    end
end
```

I am not too sure where I'm going wrong with this as I have reviewed the tutorial over and over, and it all matches from what I can see.

**EDIT # 1**

my GenRepEnt model looks like:

```
class GenRepEnt < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :general_report

end
```

**EDIT # 2**

After performing the migration and adding belongs_to :general_report to the model I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in
>   GeneralReports::GenRepEntsController#create

Comment: What does the `GenRepEnt` model look like?

Comment: Blanks with nothing in it.

Comment: Was told the has many would make it all work

Comment: Change this line `@gen_rep_ent.general_report = @gen_rep_ent` to `@gen_rep_ent.general_report_id = @general_report.id`

Comment: Thanks, That solved the Second Problem! Much Apprectiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to set `general_report` on an instance of a `GenRepEnt` class but that method doesn't exist. This is likely because the association was not set up in the `GenRepEnt` model.

In the model `gen_rep_ent.rb` add the following association:

```
belongs_to :general_report
```

After you declare this association Rails will define a few methods on each instance of `GenRepEnt` including:

```
general_report
general_report=
```

You will also need to generate a migration that will add a new column, `general_report_id`, to the `gen_rep_ents` table.

In your terminal run `rails g migration AddGeneralReportRefToGenRepEnts general_report:references`

This should generate a migration that looks something like this:

```
class AddGeneralReportRefToGenRepEnts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :gen_rep_ents, :general_report, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Next, run the migration using `rake db:migrate` and restart your app.

Read more about the belongs_to association [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference).

Comment: so after I added belongs_to :general_report to the GenRepEnt model i get the exact same error after doing a server restart and loged out and logged back into the app..?

Comment: that worked, i think however now i get the following (ill also update question) ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in GeneralReports::GenRepEntsController#create and still refrenced the same old problem.